# How to make discord bot reply messages to user such that no one else can see the messages in channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am new to discord and trying to make a bot which on getting a command by user will make a reply to the user where the messages between user and bot will be only visible to the user who used the command. I am not able to get how to do it. Here is my code source for the following:

```
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    message.reply("Enter your email Id please? you have some time of 100 seconds")
        .then(msg => msg.delete(10000)) // so the message will delete after the time is up (10 seconds)
            .catch(err => {}) // if the bot hasnt got perms to delete the message, it will ignore the error 
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1, // do NOT change this 
        time: 10000, // this is the time in MS you want it to last. (There are 1000 MS in 1 second)
        errors: ['time'] // this ensures the only error is "time"
    }).then(async(collected) => { // collected is a collection so we use collected.first().content
        if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'cancel') { // .toLowerCase() converts the user input to lower case, so if they type "CaNcEl" it will still be read as "cancel" and the if statement will run
            message.reply(":sob: The command has been cancelled.") // what to do if the user repleis "cancel"
        } 
       email = collected.first().content; // finally send the collected message content to the message channel
       if(email == emailregistered){
        console.log(email);
        message.reply("Check your DM please!");
        }else{
        message.reply("Sorry You are not authorized! Please contact  team to get access to the channel!");
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        message.reply("You took too long!")
    })
       
    }else{
        message.reply("Channel Name does not exist, Try contacting  Dev");
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use the following to output messages:

```
await message.channel.send("TEST")
```

To send the user a direct message you use the following:

```
await message.author.send("TEST")
```